# Htaccess and php Session weird results seems like [L] not working properly

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, session

I currently have this URL **mysite.com/en/store/storage** to maintain in a SESSION variable. Everything echo correctly as long as I don't have an html invalid file on my site.

Here is my htaccess file that is getting the error:

```
RewriteEngine On
rewritecond $1 \.(gif¦jpg¦css¦xml)$ [OR]
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule (.*) - [S=3] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*) index.php?lang=$1&type=$2&cat=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?lang=$1&type=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?lang=$1&type=1 [L]
```

When I **remove the last 2 lines**, everything works fine on this level. Of course I need the other lines to be applied to parent's levels.

It seems like **[L]** is not stopping the htaccess and is altering my SESSION variable that is coded like that on php:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION["actualLink"]." -- test 1 ";
    $_SESSION["actualLink"] = $_GET["lang"]."/".$_GET["type"]."/".$_GET["cat"];
    echo "<img src=\"mysite.com/images/wrongpath.jpg\"/>";
    echo $_SESSION["actualLink"]." test 2 ";
?>
```

The result of this with the entire htaccess always gives that on page reload:

**mysite.com/wrongimagepath.jpg test1 -- mysite.com/en/store/storage test2**

With the 2 last lines removed here is the desired result:

**mysite.com/en/store/storage test1 -- mysite.com/en/store/storage test2**

The problem is that I need these lines (that are causing the problem on dynamic subfolders):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?lang=$1&type=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?lang=$1&type=1 [L]
```

to be applied to pages like:

```
mysite.com/en/store
mysite.com/en
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: It is unclear what is the exact problem you're facing. Can you clarify with examples?

Comment: @anubhava I added some examples and desired results, so it is probably a bit clearer. Hopes that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpe?g|js|css|xml)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule ^ - [L] 

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&type=$2&cat=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&type=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&type=1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It seems like only this line: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpe?g|js|css|xml)$ [NC,OR]` is the right alternative thank you!